# Google Analytics and iOS Appstore push

Tags: ios, swift, google-analytics, app-store

I'm using Google analytics in my app to sent the screen names.Do i need to take care of any other advertising id that may be present in Google Analytics SDK That may cause any issue with Appstore Push.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the GA docs,
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/#headers

> To use the IDFA (Identifier for Advertisers) requires that you link
>   the following files to your app and then enable IDFA collection:
>
> libAdIdAccess.a AdSupport.framework Note: depending on your build
>   settings, the linker flag -force_load /path/to/libAdIdAccess.a may be
>   required.

As long as you don't do that, it will not use the Advertising ID, and it will not impact your app submission.

Comment: I have seen libAdIdAccess.a in the downloaded SDK but im not linking it in project.Im using only libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a file.Should i remove libAdIdAccess.a from the folder itself?Will it have any other impact?

Comment: If you aren't linking, then it won't be part of the final binary.  You won't have any issues.